Scientist who says where Dr Manhattan is in Watchmen - actor name?
I'm trying to figure out who this actor in Watchmen is, but I don't know what his character's name is.  I found a transcript of the movie, but his character is just called "MAN" in it, so that's no help.  I've looked through all the characters listed on IMDB, and I'm pretty sure he's not any of the 'scientist' characters, but maybe he has multiple parts and so he's listed under a different name that I'm not expecting.  He's the guy who runs in and says they found Dr. Manhattan, and that he's on Mars.  (on the left in the image) (I swear I know him from something and I'm going to kick myself when I realize who he is)


Looks like Alessandro Juliani - He had a recurring role on Smallville, and currently on The 100.

I think this is Alessandro Juliani from Battlestar Galactica and recently The 100. He is on the cast list, just way down.


You beat me.  The character name is Rockefeller Military Base Technician.

That's him! Agh! And I was totally remembering Battlestar Galactica! I missed 'technician' when I read the list!
